# How to install Ubuntu 13.10 Desktop in QEMU?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, qemu

Following are the details of my system: Fedora Core-18, i686.

I am trying to  install ubuntu in the qemu. Following are the commands I executed:

```
qemu-img create ubuntu.img 8G
qemu-system-i386 -hda ubuntu.img -boot d -cdrom ./ubuntu-13.10-desktop-i386.iso -m 512
```

After executing the second command the window pops up and it shows UBUNTU getting started but after that the window just becomes black with no activity.

Comment: I think the problem is that qemu lacks graphical support for unity. Try booting lubutnu (or other ubuntu variant).

Comment: Are you using regular Qemu or KVM?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are emulating and not virtualizing, and emulating is resource consuming, so the boot takes a very long time to finish.

To speed things up, add the `-enable-kvm` flag to enable KVM virtualization:

```
qemu-system-i386 -hda ubuntu.img -boot d -cdrom ./ubuntu-13.10-desktop-i386.iso -m 512 -enable-kvm
```

This has also been asked at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/419958/why-am-i-getting-a-black-screen-when-booting-vm-using-qemu

Comment: Edit and explain something about how this link is useful.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but that link is just a reference! Said just to mention the reference.

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify whether you're using QEMU or KVM, but as [@BodhiZazen said in the comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108122/installing-ubuntu-13-0-desktop-in-qemu#comment166384_108122), I don't think vanilla QEMU can support high end graphics such as what Unity requires.

If you're actually trying to use KVM, then I'd recommend using the GUI tool `virt-manager` to perform your VM Guest installations rather than the command line. It's easier to mount ISO media and reconfigure the Guest VM through the GUI.

#### Screenshots

[image: ss of virtmanager #1]

[image: ss of virtmanager #2]

You can see more of `virt-manager` [in action](http://virt-manager.org/screenshots/) on the [project's website](http://virt-manager.org/) and read about it features there as well.

Comment: I was using qemu. I will switch on to kvm.

Answer (score 0):

**Working Ubuntu 18.04 host / guest setup**

I cannot reproduce with the following setup:

```
wget http://releases.ubuntu.com/xenial/ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso
qemu-img create -f qcow2 ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.img.qcow2 16G
qemu-system-x86_64 \
  -cdrom ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso \
  -drive file=ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.qcow2,format=qcow2 \
  -enable-kvm \
  -m 2G \
  -smp 2 \
  -vga virtio \
;
```

Then on the GUI:

- Install Ubuntu
- continue, continue, continue...
- wait a few minutes
- at the end "Restart now"
- now you can close the QEMU window

After the install is complete, I recommend [using a disk snapshot](https://wiki.qemu.org/index.php/Documentation/CreateSnapshot) in case you ever want to go back to the pristine install (a common use case for testing software):

```
qemu-img create -f qcow2 -b ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.qcow2 \
                            ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.snapshot.qcow2
```

and then restart the system from the snapshot disk:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \
  -drive file=ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.snapshot.qcow2,format=qcow2 \
  -enable-kvm \
  -m 2G \
  -smp 2 \
  -vga virtio \
;
```

Then anytime you want to go back to the pristine install, just re-run:

```
qemu-img create -f qcow2 -b ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.qcow2 \
                            ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.snapshot.qcow2
```

The snapshot only stores the diffs between the original image, and so it does not take a lot of disk space.

Tested on an Ubuntu 18.04 host, QEMU `1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.3`, `nvidia-384` version `390.48-0ubuntu3`, Lenovo ThinkPad P51, `NVIDIA Corporation GM107GLM [Quadro M1200 Mobile]` GPU.

[image]

Notes:

- `-vga virtio` option is to be able to get higher resolutions: https://superuser.com/questions/132322/how-to-increase-the-visualized-screen-resolution-on-qemu-kvm/1331924#1331924 Toggle full screen with:

  ```
  Ctrl + Alt + F
  ```

  of start QEMU with `-full-screen`.
- `-soundhw hda` enables sound. Why does not QEMU enable it by default beats me.
- Once inside the VM, reduce the GRUB menu wait time and show some boot messages for next boot with:

  ```
  printf 'GRUB_TIMEOUT=1\nGRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""\n' | sudo tee -a /etc/default/grub
  sudo update-grub
  ```
- TODO clipboard sharing:

  - [virt-manager copy paste functionality to the vm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109117/virt-manager-copy-paste-functionality-to-the-vm)
  - https://askubuntu.com/questions/858649/how-can-i-copypaste-from-the-host-to-a-kvm-guest
  - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/QEMU#SPICE
  - https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/SPICE

  Tried `-spice port=5930,disable-ticketing` + `remote-viewer spice://127.0.0.1:5930`, and `spice-vdagent` is pre-installed on guest, but no success.

  The root cause of the mess is that QEMU devs seem more focused on non-interactive usage, rather than implementing things like this reliably and therefore killing VirtualBox once and for all: https://bugs.launchpad.net/qemu/+bug/614958
- TODO: host 3D acceleration. Still with SPICE and QXL, `glxgears` gives 1k FPS, and the exact same with regular SDL. But on host `__GL_SYNC_TO_VBLANK=0 vblank_mode=0 glxgears` gives 20k FPS, so I'm guessing graphics were not accelerated?

Related: [How to install Ubuntu 13.10 Desktop in QEMU?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108122/installing-ubuntu-13-0-desktop-in-qemu)

**Prebuilt bootable images**

If you want an image that boots without the need for any interaction on the installer, see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/281763/is-there-any-prebuilt-qemu-ubuntu-image32bit-online